# How long to wait before following up with conductors?

Tags: orchestra, conducting

An emerging composer is seeking to have some of their work performed by a smallish professional orchestra (i.e. *not* something like the Boston Symphony, but a fairly well-known regional symphony).  The composer was introduced to the conductor through a well-respected mutual acquaintance.  The conductor has most likely not heard of the composer before the introduction.
Following the introduction, the conductor responded to the composer and asked for a sample of work.  Assuming that the composer dutifully provided the requested materials in a prompt and professional manner, how long is it appropriate for the composer to wait before following up?

Obviously, they could wait forever and still never get a response, forgotten along with all the other composers who solicited that conductor that month, where a quick follow-up might have helped.  But also obvious is the fact that the composer could nag the conductor and spoil the nice introduction.  This would earn them a quick "no thanks" just for being a pain.

So, what is the appropriate interval to wait?

EDIT: By *emerging composer*, let's assume that the composer has been commissioned for several pieces and won a handful of minor contests.  Their work has been performed by a few professional ensembles, but mostly by local, amateur groups.

Comment: You might consider also posting this question — or one substantially similar — to [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/). They field questions of this type ("how long to wait to contact the hiring manager" sorts of questions), and a cursory search suggests they haven't had one that deals with this sort of approach to "getting hired".

Comment: Thanks @Aaron here is the alternate question on Workplace.  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/174814/how-long-to-wait-before-following-up-with-conductors

Comment: It will mostly depend on when said conductor has the opportunity to find time and an orchestra to actually perform said piece.

Comment: As much as I like this question, I’m voting to close it, because it's off-topic per the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page "...and it is not about business or legal issues ".

Comment: @Aaron closing makes sense especially since it seems to fit so much better on workplace.  Should I delete this?

Comment: @nuggethead I wouldn't: while it might fit on workplace, as a user pointed out, there's little chance to get a *focused* answer on a field that's so specific and peculiar. You could get some generic insight for *similar* areas: arts related, but not in the strict sense, as this could apply to any work that can't be "objectively reviewable". Other people could give some valid opinion, but they would hardly understand the insights and complex (and sometimes unpredictable/inconsistent/just wrong) dynamics an actual artist, musician, composer or conductor might have.

Comment: On the other hand, this question *is* opinion based, as it's not strictly about practice and theory. But, let's say it, we're all about music, not 0s and 1s, we're not on stackoverflow. It would hardly fit any other SE site except for workplace (which doesn't mean that it's fine just because here we talk about music and the question is music related), so it's a bit *fringe*. You've got "just" one close vote and an answer from an experienced SE user, meaning that not many others believed it's *that* off-topic. So, for the time being, leave it here. Just consider all this for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

I was a professional orchestral musician and am a composer, so I can identify with your question.  If say two weeks have passed and still no reaction, then it would be perfectly reasonable to send a short message asking for any critical response or suggestions regarding the piece that the conductor might have.  Just get the ball rolling again.  Other than that, could the 'well-respected mutual acquaintance' maybe casually ask the conductor about it?